# ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest not found

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I was following the tutorial listed [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html) to create my first blockchain network. but when I run `./startfabric.sh` it gives me the error

```
# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating network "net_basic" with the default driver
Pulling couchdb (hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest)...
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest not found
```

Any help on how I could fix this?

Comment: I understand that a `latest` tag is not created/mentioned in the [repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-couchdb/tags/) but how can I fix this?

Comment: I understand that a `latest` tag is not created/mentioned in the [repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-couchdb/tags/) but how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed the step with "[Download Platform-specific Binaries](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html)", which basically takes care to download all relevant images and binary files, such that you won't have to compile them.

Comment: Updated, apparently was moved after release of v1.1

Answer (score 0):

Please download the version of couchdb manually.

```
docker pull "hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:<version>"
```

create a tag with latest.

```
docker image tag hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:<version> hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:latest
```

NOTE:

Solution is only for this case. Why fabric-couchdb with latest tag is missing in docker hub is to be investigated.